# hyperledger-explorer can not connect to provisioned Postgres instance on IBM Cloud

Tags: postgresql, ibm-cloud, hyperledger, hyperledger-explorer

I'm trying to connect hyperledger-explorer to IBM Cloud Databases for Postgres instance. I provide the correct credentials to connect to DB. However, the app gives authentication errors.

```
[2021-08-19T10:38:01.088] [ERROR] PgService - error when connecting to db: error: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "172.30.229.241", user "ibm_cloud_a55353b8_7766_4dbb_9c6b_89ee7b666773", database "ibmclouddb", SSL off
    at Connection.parseE (/opt/explorer/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:614:13)
    at Connection.parseMessage (/opt/explorer/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:413:19)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/opt/explorer/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:129:22)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:297:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:273:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:214:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:186:23) {
```

From inside the explorer pod, I installed psql -for investigation- and tried to connect to my instance using

```
PGPASSWORD=xxx  psql 'host=xxx po
rt=xxx dbname=ibmclouddb user=ibm_cloud_user'
```

and it works, I was able to connect to the DB.

I'm sure the application uses incorrect connection strings to DB. But, I can't see what it sends to verify

any idea how can I resolve this?

Comment: This is Pg error you get when database is not configured to accept connections from your machine. The default config by IBM probably allows clients from their own data center, but if you want to connect from other locations you need to add your IP range to the firewall. You probably want to check this doc: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/databases-for-postgresql?topic=cloud-databases-allowlisting

Comment: What do you get if add `PGSSLMODE=disable`  to the front of your `psql` command?

Comment: Well the user name is certainly different between the two attempts.

Comment: @jjanes thanks for your response, the user is the same I just gave an example of what I used to check the connection to the database.

I tried with SSL disabled same error

Comment: @Cninroh that's correct. But with IBM Cloud Database for Postgres, the provided user name with the password should work directly without any extra configuration needed for authentication. When I tested the access using `psql` it works. But, once I change the user name or entered the password incorrectly I got same error of `no pg_hba.conf entry for host`

Comment: @Houssini If you check the content of pg_hba.conf, you will see that IP range and username combo is what is permitted access, and not just the user. There is a handy view built in Pg to simplify checking this once you are connected. Just issue SQL: "SELECT * FROM pg_hba_file_rules;" Check for more: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/auth-pg-hba-conf.html